# Any scripture mentions naagmani?

Tags: scripture, puranas, itihasa

Is naagmani a fictional thing or mentioned in scriptures? Also what about those special kind of naags?

Comment: It is mentioned in scriptures. Takshaka gave one such mani to a brahmana who was on his way to save Parikshit, but that brahmana foresaw future that Parikshit was going to Moksha so he turned around without saving him.

Comment: @ram sir if you are free then can you please wrote whole amswer about it? I am curious about why takshak wanted to save parikshit.

Comment: @Rickross yes but according to an answer there, there are multiple naag manis. Is that true?

Comment: I'm not sure you can ask the author of the answer. He might know the answer. @Rudra

Comment: Takshaka did not want to save Parikshit. He gave his mani to a brahmin who wanted to save Parikshit